# Python: Iterating over list and vectors within list at the same time, only changing pairs of list[i][i]

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to make a function that yields a matrix like this:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

(but then with 40 rows of 40 numbers instead of 4*4)

What I have now is:

```
def create_weights_hid_con():
    weights_list = []
    weight_vector = []
    for i in range(0, 40):
        weight_vector.append(0.0)
    for i in range(0, 40):
        weights_list.append(weight_vector)
    for i in range(0, len(weights_list)):
        weights_list[i][i] = 1.0
    return weights_list
```

I thought this would do:

```
weights_list[0][0] = 1.0
weights_list[1][1] = 1.0
weights_list[2][2] = 1.0
etc.
```

But instead it also does everything in between, which yields a matrix like this:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

So my question is: what can I do to make it change only the numbers for which the first and the second index are the same? (e.g. do change weights_list[0][0], but don't change weights_list[0][1]).

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you are storing the same list over and over:

```
    weights_list.append(weight_vector)
```

So, when you go through it, the changes affect every list.  It will work if you force a copy, like:

```
    weights_list.append(weight_vector[:])
```

It's also not clear why you're appending to the weight vector each time. It would make more sense to simply initialize it like:

```
weight_vector = [0.0] * 40
```

although the whole lot could be summed up as a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[int(i == j) for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you're not adding a new list when you do an `append`, you're adding a reference to the *same* list. This is a bit of an overly complex way of doing what you want to do anyway, however:

```
weights = [[0.0]*40 for i in range(40)]
for j in range(40):
    weights[j][j] = 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are trying to contruct the identity matrix. Take a look at [numpy.identity()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html): Ex:

```
>>> np.identity(3)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

If you still want a list just use [numpy.tolist()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
weights = [[float(i==j) for i in range(40)] for j in range(40)]
```